# ionic how to identify clicked button in a *ngFor loop

Tags: html, button, ionic-framework

I am creating a list of text and buttons.
I want to identify which button has been clicked in the clicked function.

HTML

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item ion-item *ngFor="let act of questions.test">
      {{act.quote}}
      <ion-item>
        <button large ion-button item-right (click)="SelectClicked()">Select</button>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

TS

```
  this.questions =
  {
    "test":[
    {
      "quote": "first row"
    }, {
      "quote": "second row"
    }, {
      "quote": "third row"
    }, {
      "quote": "fourth row"
    }
    ]
  }


SelectClicked(detail){
//please help
// which button was clicked ( 1 to 4 ) ?
  console.log("SelectClicked" + detail);
}
```

Comment: If you're just concerned with the index of selected element, pass `index` as an argument like SelectClicked(index)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am guessing that you want the selected element, that can be done by passing on the event to the handler.

```
<button (click)="SelectClicked($event)"></button>
```

Which you can fetch the element from the event with using `event.target`, `event.srcElement` or `event.currentTarget`.

But if you mean to pass along the index or the item of your array, you can just pass on that `act` object or add an index to the loop...

```
<ion-item ion-item *ngFor="let act of questions.test; let i = index">
```

...and pass on the object...

```
<button (click)="SelectClicked(act)"></button>
```

...or the id

```
<button (click)="SelectClicked(i)"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the "act" value as a parameter to the function like this

```
 <button large ion-button item-right 
  (click)="SelectClicked(act)">Select
 </button>
```